# Má tradução "Perguntadas", "Visualizadas" e "Ativo"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito o correto seria:

> Perguntada
>
> Visualizada
>
> Ativa

Pois se refere à `Pergunta`, no singular e no feminino. Concordam? Discordam?

Comment: Só colocaria Perguntou, ao invés de perguntada.

Comment: "Perguntada" está errado é "Perguntou" ou "Criada"

Comment: @JorgeB. pq não "Perguntada"? Você acha que está errado ou acha que não está apropriado? São coisas diferentes :)

Comment: @Math acho que não está apropriado, não me expliquei bem. Não me soa bem, soa melhor "Criada há 7 dias". "A pergunta foi perguntada há 7 dias" ou "A pergunta foi criada há 7 dias". Fica a sugestão.

Comment: @JorgeB. De fato "a pergunta foi perguntada" soa estranho, mas o "Perguntada" sozinho me parece razoável. Talvez o "Criada" pudesse ficar melhor mesmo, mas você bem que podia ter sugerido antes né não? rsrs.. Se quiser, publique uma resposta com essa sugestão. Vai que vc recebe um apoio enorme e o texto não muda de novo.

Comment: @Math eu ainda não estava no site quando essa pergunta foi feita ;)

Answer (score 1):

Concordo, principalmente por se referir à pergunta atual, no singular.